# Beautify JSON for Angular Material Table Cell

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-material

I'm using Material UI for Angular. I'm working with a Table (mat-table) where I have a cell (mat-cell) that needs to have JSON beautified. My goal is to make each key-value pair on it's own line, within the Table's cell.

I've tried "\n".

I tried placing each key-value pair inside a , but the div tags are printed to the screen as literals.

I've also tried JSON.stringify(value, this.replacer, 2)

None of the above solutions worked so far. Any help would be appreciated.

**The raw JSON:**

```
{"MobilePhone":"3238759873","OtherPhone":"3238759871"}
```

**What I want it to look like:**

MobilePhone : 3238759873

OtherPhone : 3238759871

**Material UI Column Definition**

```
<!-- Prevous Definition -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="previous">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header
      ><b>Previous</b></mat-header-cell
    >
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let record">{{
      getValuesText(record.oldValues)
    }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

**Beautify**

```
getValuesText(values: string): string {
   //return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(values), this.replacer, 2);
   let str: string[] = [];
   var json_parsed = JSON.parse(values);
   for (let name in json_parsed) {
     str.push(name + ' : ' + json_parsed[name]);
     str.push('\n');
   }
   return str.join('');
 }
/*
replacer(key: string, value: any) {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      return value === null ? '' : JSON.stringify(value, this.replacer, '\t');
    }

    return value;
  }*/
```

[image: Example]

Comment: If you want to add linebreak to HTML, you need to insert `<br>` to your string instead of `\n`. But because of this now you must use `[innerHTML]` which may lead to security issues. Why don't you iterate over object in your template? Replace `getValuesText` with proper template where you iterate over object and render text and markup you actually need

Comment: I like what Zerdox says! You need to modify the html code of each cell depending on how many entries your Raw Json has. For example, iterate through your record object and for each key / value pair add a div cotnaining the data. (the div has to be inside the mat-cell, you can ue ngFor for that). I hope my way of explaining and Zerdox's way of explaining is helpful!

Comment: Thank you both. @Mihai this is the solution that almost worked for me. It did not work by default, because mat-cell expects only a single element. So I wrapped the ngFor divs into one parent div.